# pjsua auto answer with delay

Tags: sip, pjsip

I am using pjsua as command line SIP client and it works just fine and is capable to auto answer call automatically but i would like to somehow use auto answer delay. Configuration I have works fine but pjsua client answer the call immediately. The thing i need is some delay before call is answered with 200 OK.
Any help would be welcome

My config file contains:

```
   # dont use hosts audio device
   --null-audio
   # Logging options:
   --log-level=3
   --app-log-level=3
   --log-file=LOG-File.log
   # Account 0:
   --id=sip:100@test-lab.org
   # SIP Signal IP addr
   --registrar=sip:test-lab.org
   --reg-timeout=3600
   --proxy=sip:10.20.21.254
   --realm=test-lab.org
   --username=100@test-lab.org
   --password=12345678
   --use-timer=1
   --use-ims
   --auto-update-nat=1
   # Network settings:
   --local-port=5065
   --ip-addr=10.100.100.25
   --bound-addr=10.100.100.25
   --no-tcp
   --outbound=sip:10.20.21.254;lr
   # Media settings:
   --ptime=20
   --rtp-port=8000
   #
   --snd-auto-close=1
   # User agent:
   --max-calls 6
   --add-codec=pcma
   --clock-rate=8000
   --auto-play
   --duration=300
   --play-file=music.wav
   --auto-answer=200
   --no-vad
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible to add delay through configuration, so you would have to modify pjsua_app.c and add some timer there.

Comment: Yes. I think so. I was looking and going through pjsua man and did not find any parameter like this. I thought at the end i should change pjsua_app.c but i do not know where and how

Comment: One way of doing this: add timestamp to app_config.call_data[call_id] structure, fill this timestamp after if (app_config.auto_answer > 0) instead of calling pjsua_call_answer2(). At startup create timer called periodically with e.g. 10ms interval, inside callback timer poll all call_data structures and answer for calls that timestamp "expired". Side note: for similar tests I'm using either SIPp or tSIP softphone, they allow to specify randomized time for auto answer

Comment: thx for your reply and help. I am not that much into C coding i will try to see with some of my colleagues if they could take look into code.